# Xiaomi Mi A1 proximity sensor not working

Tags: xiaomi, proximity-sensor, mi-a1

I just got a new Mi A1, not even a week old, and in the middle of calls my cheek is turning on the loudspeaker, muting, etc. Clearly the proximity sensor is poorly calibrated/not working.

Is there any easy way to fix this or should I return for a refund?

Comment: [this answer](/a/112735/16575) mentions calibrating the proximity sensor (not sure if that's available on all devices – the post was about a Yureka); but same answer [here](/a/106099/16575) for a Micromax, so it might be worth checking. Other probable causes: sensor dirty (clean it), or you use a cover which is, ahem, covering the sensor?

Comment: There is a miA1 tag :) ; added that to your question

Comment: I have also faced the same issue with my MI A1. I think there is some kind of software issue that MI needs fixing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was actually pretty simple. [This post](http://www.androidbeat.com/2016/10/fix-proximity-sensor-not-working-issue-redmi-note-3/) suggests a couple of solutions, but the first one worked for me:

> Restart your phone.

Comment: @RahulGopi The correct code is `*#*#64663#*#*`. I think your text treated the outside asterisks as *italic* formatting ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The latest December 156 MB update seems to have resolved this issue.

The problem is with AOSP Phone app. If the latest update has not resolved the issue, install google dialer apk & make it  default.

Comment: I couldn't download December  update, and now it even doesn't appear in system updates!